# is it possible to pass a class<protocol> as parameter?

Tags: android, android-intent

Actually I want to create a function that will be able to handle multiple types of ArrayList.

```
public void someFunction(Class ArrayList<protocol>) {
    ArrayList<?> object = new ArrayList<protocol>;
}
```

Something like that, any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it help u..

```
public class TestClass {

    public void function(List<? extends Object> temp){

        ArrayList<? extends Object> obj=(ArrayList<? extends Object>) temp;


        }
}
```

Then you may call this function in this way using different type of parameter.

```
        TestClass test= new TestClass();

        test.function(new ArrayList<String>());
        test.function(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        test.function(new ArrayList<TestClass>());
```

Comment: I think generics are more appropiate, since using Object here can lead to runtime errors, because of casting, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are probably looking for the power of [generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java), something like this might help:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
  public void someFunction(ArrayList<T> myArray)
  {
   ... //do anything with generic T array.
  }
}
```

Then you could easily instantiate MyClass, and call method `someFunction` with compile-safe coding.

Good Luck

Comment: I think this is it but lets say A and B are subtypes of T, how would I be able to tell if it is A or if it is B?

Comment: T is not a type at all, is just a parameter to be swapped by the actual type you want to.